# swiftの <| 記法

Tags: swift

[ikesyo/Himotoki: A type-safe JSON decoding library purely written in Swift](https://github.com/ikesyo/Himotoki)

引用：

```
static func decode(_ e: Extractor) throws -> Group {
        return try Group(
            name: e <| "name",
            floor: e <| "floor",
            locationName: e <| [ "location", "name" ], // Parse nested objects
            optional: e <||? "optional" // Parse optional arrays of values
        )
```

に出てくる `<|` は、なんでしょうか？　上手く検索にひっかりません。

Comment: 自前で定義していますね。https://github.com/ikesyo/Himotoki/blob/master/Sources/Operators.swift#L9

Comment: リンク先に**Extraction Operators** として説明がありますね。つまり自作演算子。

Comment: swiftってこいうことができたんですね。失礼しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[swiftの <| 記法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33843/swift%E3%81%AE-%E8%A8%98%E6%B3%95#comment33322_33843)

コメントに頂いた通り、自前で定義したものです。

https://github.com/ikesyo/Himotoki/blob/master/Sources/Operators.swift#L9